# Неправильное вращение

Tags: c#, unity3d

Воспользовался Quaternion.Euler() для вращения объектов. Дело в том, что они вращаются очень резко и сразу же вращение возвращается в начальное положение. С чем это может быть связано? На объектах нет никаких заморозок вращения. Пробовал все вращать с помощью Rotate(), получилось, но с помощью его нельзя ограничивать угол. Помогите разобраться с Quaternion.Euler()

```
    [![Vector3 MoveTPl;
    public float speed;
    public float RotateSpeed;
    MoveTestPlayer MTP;
    Camera cam;

   public float curRotX;
   public float curRotY;
   public float XrotateVelocity;
   public float YrotateVelocity;

    public float Ry;
    public float Rx;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        MTP = GetComponent<MoveTestPlayer>();
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 Mx = transform.right * x;
        Vector3 Mz = transform.forward * z;

        Vector3 MoveTPl = (Mx + Mz).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        MTP.MoveTPlayer(MoveTPl);

         Ry = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*4;
         Rx = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")*4;

        Rx = Mathf.Clamp(Rx, -90, 90);

        curRotY = Mathf.SmoothDamp(curRotY, Ry, ref XrotateVelocity, 0.1f);
        curRotX = Mathf.SmoothDamp(curRotX, Rx, ref YrotateVelocity, 0.1f);

        cam.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-curRotX, 0, 0);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, curRotY, 0);





        //cam.transform.Rotate(-curRotX, 0, 0);
        //transform.Rotate(0, curRotY, 0);
    }][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

C углами Эйлера есть такой неприятный момент как [шарнирный замок(gimbal lock)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA) и следует понимать что из углов Эйлера вы можете получить только один `Quaternion`, а обратное преобразование может возвращать несколько разных вариантов углов Эйлера обеспечивающих один и тот же разворот объекта.

У вас вроде бы преобразований туда/обратно нет, и ошибка мне кажется в том что вы в качестве конечного значения используете состояние оси мыши. Вот если бы вы брали `Input.mousePosition` то получали бы положение мыши в координатах экрана и их можно было бы посчитать относительно центра и высчитывать степень поворота. А вы берете смещение по оси смещения указателя и как только мышь перестает двигаться ось возвращает 0, и вы возвращаетесь в исходное положение потому что в `curRotY = Mathf.SmoothDamp(curRotY, Ry, ref XrotateVelocity, 0.1f);` мы стремимся к цели `Ry = 0.0f`.

Comment: проблема была решена таким образом

Comment: Ry += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*4;
         Rx += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")*4;

Comment: я бы сделал `Ry = curRotY + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*4;' раз у вас в этих переменных хранятся текущие значения.